# Highlight out of date cells

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

currently I have a spread sheet of dates. A1 is todays date 3 years ago. 
A3:A20 are various dates when employees gained their first aid certificate. 
When any cell in A3:A20 is less than A1 it would mean their certificate is out of date. I would like it to be highlighted. 
Does anyone have any ideas? mine have all failed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work in new google sheets.
In cell A1 put in todays date by using
=Now()

Go to Format, conditional formatting

Select custom formula is

Enter

=datedif(A$3:A$20,$A$1,"Y")>3

Select your colour, such as red, then finally in the range. put A3:A20

Comment: @TonyG Glad it's all working, please mark question as answered if it is. Thanks